# Visual Studio 2013 crashing multiple times a day

Tags: visual-studio-2013, crash, lockup

I have Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate with Update 4. Computer is Windows 7, 64 bit, 8gb ram, 1tb hd. Multiple times a day it will lock up and crash while I am doing normal coding operations. Sometimes its while i'm opening a file, or renaming a variable, or just typing code. It was doing this with Update 3 and Update 2. Does anyone know how to fix this?

edit 2: I started working in a secondary project for a different portion of program and noticed it only happens when working in my big project (22k lines, 70+ files). The new project im working in is only 10 files and 2k lines of code, and has not crashed for the week i've been in it so far.

edit: here is the xml error log when it crashes

```
<WERReportMetadata>
  <OSVersionInformation>
    <WindowsNTVersion>6.1</WindowsNTVersion>
    <Build>7601 Service Pack 1</Build>
    <Product>(0x1): Windows 7 Ultimate</Product>
    <Edition>Ultimate</Edition>
    <BuildString>7601.18526.amd64fre.win7sp1_gdr.140706-1506</BuildString>
    <Revision>1130</Revision>
    <Flavor>Multiprocessor Free</Flavor>
    <Architecture>X64</Architecture>
    <LCID>1033</LCID>
  </OSVersionInformation>
  <ProblemSignatures>
    <EventType>CLR20r3</EventType>
    <Parameter0>devenv.exe</Parameter0>
    <Parameter1>12.0.31101.0</Parameter1>
    <Parameter2>54548724</Parameter2>
    <Parameter3>Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ViewManager</Parameter3>
    <Parameter4>12.0.31101.0</Parameter4>
    <Parameter5>545487c9</Parameter5>
    <Parameter6>501</Parameter6>
    <Parameter7>2f</Parameter7>
    <Parameter8>System.ArgumentOutOfRange</Parameter8>
  </ProblemSignatures>
  <DynamicSignatures>
    <Parameter1>6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1</Parameter1>
    <Parameter2>1033</Parameter2>
    <Parameter22>0a9e</Parameter22>
    <Parameter23>0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789</Parameter23>
    <Parameter24>0a9e</Parameter24>
    <Parameter25>0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789</Parameter25>
  </DynamicSignatures>
  <SystemInformation>
    <MID>2AAE6B99-B3F8-41BF-BE92-B48165152E42</MID>
    <SystemManufacturer>MSI</SystemManufacturer>
    <SystemProductName>MS-7721</SystemProductName>
    <BIOSVersion>V30.3</BIOSVersion>
  </SystemInformation>
</WERReportMetadata>
```

Comment: Any chance you are saving your project in the default My Documents path, and that is stored on a domain network resource?

Comment: nope, its saved to a folder on my desktop

Comment: Do you use any cool and super-useful plugins?

Comment: Only one I use is GhostDoc.

Comment: Tried installing update 4?

Comment: Wasn't aware update 4 was out, installing now.

Comment: Installed update 4 last night, been using it today and it locked up and crashed again.

Comment: This doesn't look like an IntelliTrace issue since the problem mentions Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ViewManager. Did you opt-in to be part of the customer improvement program and send crash information to Microsoft?

Comment: I clicked on the send MS the error button to get more details on the crash. and the code above is what they game me.